# Excel summing and filtering

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with 3 columns.
Column1 is ClientName, column2 is Desrciption , column 3 is a number corresponding to the description.
I need to sum the numbers corresponding to each description of ClienName using filters or for loop.

In other words:

```
col1       col2      col3
Jason      Cash      20
Jason      Cash      30
Jason      Cash      10
Jason      Credit    20
Jason      Credit    40      
John       Cash      20
John       Cash      10
John       Credit    30
John       Credit    20
Mary       Cash      50
Mary       Cash      20
Mary       Credit    20
Mary       Credit    100
Mary       Credit    200
```

I need results like that

```
Jason   CashTotal    CreditTotal  
John    CashTotal    CreditTotal    
Mary    CashTotal    CreditTotal
```

How can this be done in Excel?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can it be done in Excel?

Comment: Please edit your post to include your attempt at a solution. Thank you.

Comment: I tried to do it using filters manually but it takes a long time cause I have about 4000 clientName entries. I need a faster way but I don't know how.

Comment: I solved it this way 


F2 = Jason
F3 = John
F4 = Mary

Code:

G2 (copied down) =SUMIFS($C$2:$C$15,$A$2:$A$15,$F2,$B$2:$B$15,"Cash")

H2 (copied down) =SUMIFS($C$2:$C$15,$A$2:$A$15,$F2,$B$2:$B$15,"Credit")

Comment: Good on you. You can certainly post that as an answer, and even accept it (click checkmark).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way

```
F2 = Jason
F3 = John
F4 = Mary
```

Code:

```
G2 (copied down) =SUMIFS($C$2:$C$15,$A$2:$A$15,$F2,$B$2:$B$15,"Cash")

H2 (copied down) =SUMIFS($C$2:$C$15,$A$2:$A$15,$F2,$B$2:$B$15,"Credit")
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, right off it seems like you want a SumIf or SumIfs. I'm still trying to test an example to see how to make it work right, but that's atleast enough for you to start digging on your own.